# How to get insights data from publish stream posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps, posts, facebook-insights

I have an experimental facebook app, which is posting to the users wall with publish_stream permission. I want to get insights data from that posts like: **posts impressions**, likes, comments, **stories created**, ...etc. In the FQL documentation I can't see such insights for applications, only for pages.

**Can I get such insights data for my application?** Should I use Open Graph actions and objects instead publish stream posts?

What are the advantages and disadvantages for Open Graph actions? I found that the publish stream posts are easier to create, because the Open Graph actions needs approval.

Please give me some ideas!

Thanks!

Comment: There are a ton of application insights you can get from the fql insights table - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#application_users. The question of whether to use Open Graph or not shouldn't be governed by the insights data alone. Open Graph is a tremendously powerful tool and lets you provide a deeply customized experience for your users. OG actions don't take too long to get approved.